# Terminal editor/pager that allows jumping to particular line based on external command or file?

Tags: terminal, less, editors, nano

I'd like to script something so that an existing process viewing a listing file jumps to a particular line. The process might be `less` or `nano` or, if need be, another pager or editor. I would, if possible, rather not start a new process like executing `nano FILE +LINE` does. I also would like it to be more direct than using the `screen` copy buffer to manually enter the new line using nano's `Ctrl+_` shortcut.

For context, on a GUI system I can use `pluma FILE +LINE` and this will open the file in MATE's editor if it isn't opened yet, but will switch to the already opened file if it is already opened. I also have a way to assign a shortcut to a "Snippet" extension command which reads the line number from a file and executes the `pluma FILE +LINE` command. I'd like something similar for a terminal-based system, which I am only accessing across ssh and `screen`.

Comment: I think this belongs in [SE software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Quasímodo: Posted to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/74956/terminal-editor-pager-that-allows-jumping-to-particular-line-based-on-external-c